# Delimiting data from a query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, delimiter

I want to write a query in C# Visual Studio 2012 on a WinForms application that delimits certain information from an Access Database. I want to be able to get rid of any data that contains a / or a @ symbol but I'm not quite sure how to write the query. It would look something like this,

```
SELECT * FROM DATE WHERE EXPRESSION *does not have a / or @*
```

If anyone could lend any help that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're connecting to the Access db file with OleDb, try this ...

```
SELECT * FROM [DATE] WHERE Not [EXPRESSION] Like '%[/@]%';
```

If you will be testing that query within an Access application session, you will likely need to change the wild card characters ...

```
SELECT * FROM [DATE] WHERE Not [EXPRESSION] Like '*[/@]*';
```

Or you can use `ALike` instead of `Like`, and this query will operate the same in either situation ...

```
SELECT * FROM [DATE] WHERE Not [EXPRESSION] ALike '%[/@]%';
```

Note `DATE` and `EXPRESSION` are both [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  Enclosing them in square brackets avoids confusing the db engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LIKE operator](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx) in Access.